# Adding The Right JPanel Listener on Java

Tags: java, swing

I Have a trouble, I want to make a minesweeper game, but I,m stuck at this point
the point is, I want that if a the panel that have no boms nearby opened, it it'll open another panel around, I know it has to use listener, but until now I haven't found the right one, so far it just open around the panel that I click but not all the opened panel

`

```
public class Buttons extends JPanel {

public Mines Mine[][];

public Buttons(){

this.setSize(400,400);

this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
Mine = new Mines[10][10]; 
String[][] P = platmain(); 
buatkotak(P);
  //this is the code of listener, but it don't work on every panel that open, but in only work on panel that I click
   for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
            int b = j;
            int c = k;       
           Mine[j][k].addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                    if (Mine[b][c].IsOpen()&&(!"Bom".equals(Mine[b][c].Jenisnya()))&&(Mine[b][c].GetTanda()==0)){   
                       if(c>1||c<9||b>1||b<9){
                           minebuttonActionPerformed(Mine[b][c+1]);
                           minebuttonActionPerformed(Mine[b][c-1]);
                           minebuttonActionPerformed(Mine[b+1][c+1]);
                           minebuttonActionPerformed(Mine[b-1][c-1]);
                           minebuttonActionPerformed(Mine[b+1][c-1]);
                           minebuttonActionPerformed(Mine[b-1][c+1]);
                           minebuttonActionPerformed(Mine[b+1][c]);
                           minebuttonActionPerformed(Mine[b-1][c]);
                       }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
private void minebuttonActionPerformed(Mines M) {                                           
    M.MineLabel.setVisible(true);
    M.minebutton.setVisible(false);        
} `
```

Comment: Instead of using a component listener on each panel, consider creating a single mouse listener add attaching it to all the panels. When mouseClicked is triggered, locate the source from MouseEvent, find the cell it represents and determine which cells need to be displayed from there...

Comment: minesweeper game in Java is about JToggleButton